# How to filter a gridview table in yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have two gridview tables currently, one shows all the data and the other i want it to show only data where id = 2. Is it possible to filter only one table without affecting the other? I know I can filter from the search model but that will affect all tables and i want it to affect only one.

Can i have two dataprovider?

This is the code in my search model:

```
class JobPlanningSearch extends JobPlanning
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'priority', 'employer_id', 'client_id', 'status', 'activity'], 'integer'],
            [['job_description', 'impediment', 'date', 'estimated_time', 'due_date'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = JobPlanning::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'priority' => $this->priority,
            'client_id' => $this->client_id,
            'employer_id' => $this->employer_id,
            'estimated_time' => $this->estimated_time,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'activity' => $this->activity,
            //'actual' => $this->actual,
            //'actual' => 1,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'job_description', $this->job_description]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'activity', $this->activity]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can have two data providers and this is the way to go.

Comment: @Bizley Ok thanks i will try and find how to do that then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two dataproviders, like this:

```
$searchModelOne = new JobPlanningSearch();        
$dataProviderOne = $searchModelOne->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProviderOne->pagination->pageParam = 'dp-one-page'; //set page param for first dataprovider
$searchModelTwo = new JobPlanningSearch();   
searchModelTwo->id = 2;     // set id = 2 in second dataprovider
$dataProviderTwo = $searchModelTwo->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProviderTwo->pagination->pageParam = 'dp-two-page'; //set page param for second dataprovider
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manipulate the DataProvider in the controller.

```
$searchModel = new JobPlanningSearch();        
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProvider->query->andWhere(['=','id',2]);
```

2. remove it from the **search** function in JobPlanningSearch.

   $query->andFilterWhere([

   ```
    /* 'id' => $this->id, */ // you must remove it from here
    'priority' => $this->priority,
    'client_id' => $this->client_id,
    'employer_id' => $this->employer_id,
    'estimated_time' => $this->estimated_time,
        ...
   ```

   ]);

In this case, the ID will always be 2.

But if you want to have a default value (the first time) and allow the user to change it, **you should skip step 2**. And add a condition in the controller:

```
...
if(count(Yii::$app->request->queryParams) == 0){
    $dataProvider->query->andWhere(['=','id',2]);
}
```

This is just an example, you should check that the ID field has not been sent in the queryparams.

Comment: But this affects all. I want it to affect only one table

Comment: Obviously you will need to create 2 dataproviders. One for each table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two searchModels, one for each GridView and of course two data providers.

Also you need to change the `formName` attribute of one of the searchModels to avoid filtering to affects both grids.

And the in the controller, when passing parameters to the `search()` method of the modified searchModel, pass the params in the new name you assigned to formName in this searchModel.